# How to disable ssl in react native windows app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

For some reason, I want to disable SSL in my development code for the React native Windows desktop app. Please advise how to do this.

I have platform-specific code for both Android and iOS to disable SSL. But didn't find an approach for doing the same in the Windows app.